# Drop pandas rows where multiple_condition is true

Tags: python, pandas

I've a `df` with 950 rows in it. Let's pretend that the columns are `timestamp`, `quantity`, `event`, `file`. This is a good approximation of `df`. I want to:

- select all rows where `event` is `this_event` and `file` is `this_file`
- and drop the rows if the row has the same `timestamp` as a row where `file` is `my_file` and the `quantity`'s match.

How do I do that? Really struggling. I don't know how to manage this.

EDIT:

Example data:

```
timestamp,  event,  quantity,   file
2018-10-17 02:01:00,    slept,  7,  base
2018-10-17 02:01:00,    slept,  7,  temp
2018-10-17 02:01:00,    slept,  9,  base
2018-10-17 02:04:00,    studied,    5,  temp
2018-10-17 02:04:00,    farted, 7,  temp
2018-10-17 02:04:00,    drank,  1,  base
2018-10-17 02:04:00,    exercised,  8,  base
2018-10-17 02:04:00,    slept,  7,  base
```

So for example I will always keep records that pertain from file `base`. This is a bias I want to keep as these records cannot be removed. I want to delete any record from any other `file` that isn't `base`, e.g. here `temp`, where the `timestamp` and `event` is the same as any of those relating to `base` (at the same timestamp) **but only when** the `quantity` is the same as an entry from `base` (at the same timestamp).

So in this example data I would expect the code to identify the 2nd entry down and remove this because the quantity `7` is the same as one of the two other's of `base`.

The code would not delete anything from 02:04:00 because there are no rows with the same timestamp and `event` strings (events are all unique).

Comment: Could you show a small example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Comment: @KaranRazdan - I've updated with example data.

Comment: @macaw_9227 - my question is not equal to that question.

Comment: @uncle-junky, no not exactly, but it is very similar, and the top answer on that question will solve your problem (if you do your 2 steps one after another)

Comment: @macaw_9227 - I am checking and will update here if it solves it for me.

Comment: Other option is to do it with `groupby` on timestamp and quantity, and removeing rows  from there

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many way to solve it. here is my sample code for your reference.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO
from pprint import pprint

text = """
timestamp,event,quantity,file
2018-10-17 02:01:00,slept,7,base
2018-10-17 02:01:00,slept,7,temp
2018-10-17 02:01:00,slept,9,base
2018-10-17 02:04:00,studied,5,temp
2018-10-17 02:04:00,farted,7,temp
2018-10-17 02:04:00,drank,1,base
2018-10-17 02:04:00,exercised,8,base
2018-10-17 02:04:00,slept,7,base
"""

df =pd.read_csv(StringIO(text))
print("original dataframe is")
pprint(df)

qty = 7
my_file = 'temp'
my_event = 'slept'
cols =["event","quantify","file"]
qty_check = grp["quantity"].transform(lambda x: x==qty)
evt_check = grp["event"].transform(lambda x: x==my_event)

file_check = grp["event"].transform(lambda x: x==my_file)
combined_check = evt_check & qty_check & file_check
print("\ndropped dataframe is")   
pprint(df[combined_check])
```

psl refer to pandas groupby/transform section as well.
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation
note: you may find the filter functions as well. but as far as I know i can filter groups instead of the rows in groups

Comment: You're only filtering out lines with 'slept' and 'base'. This does not include the logic of what I described. The code would need `import datetime` in there to compare `timestamp` values, for example. Appreciate the effort though, just isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes. The original one not catch all logical. I updated already.

Comment: Is it possible to update the code with `groupby()` on `timestamp` and then perform the `combined_check`?